# is it possible to integration solace with vertx?

Tags: vert.x, solace, solace-mq

for our project to be successfully migrated to vertx, we need to integrate with Solace, is it possible? can any one point me to examples?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From http://vertx.io/docs/, it looks like you can simply connect to Solace via the MQTT or AMQP protocol.

Examples are just listed from their website:

- https://github.com/vert-x3/vertx-examples/tree/master/mqtt-examples
- https://github.com/vert-x3/vertx-examples/tree/master/amqp-bridge-examples